# How to control style of the button using Microsoft Web framework?

Tags: css

I am using [Microsoft Web framework](http://getmwf.com/).

Following the [button document](http://getmwf.com/components/form/button.html),

```
<button name="button" class="c-button" type="submit">Button</button>
```

gives me a blue button.

I want to use the type `button`, however, it gives me a gray button.

```
<button name="button" class="c-button" type="button">Button</button>
```

How can I control the style of the button correctly? Thanks

<kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/4vbymv5u/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, MWF targets the type attribute with CSS specifically to achieve the goal of design consistency across Microsoft properties.  Every use of a type="button" is styled the same.  Similarly, every use of type="submit" also is styled similarly.  This ensures that if one day MWF decides to change this style all websites using this markup will receive the updated style at the same time.

The architecture for MWF is quite different than other frameworks like Bootstrap, Foundation, Material etc. This is because we're designing specifically to meet Microsoft Design Language guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

From your js Fiddle, it looks like that button is getting its background color from this: .btn, a.c-button[role=button], button.c-button. To override it simply put the following in your css file.

```
.btn, a.c-button[role=button], button.c-button {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

It's often helpful to use the developer tools in your browser to inspect an element and see how the styles are being applied.